# How can I fool a site that looks at the JavaScript object 'navigator' to see that I'm not on Windows?

Tags: javascript, browser, user-agent

I am trying to browse a website, however, it only works under Windows and Mac because they use the `navigator.platform` from JavaScript to find out the architecture I am running on. Of course, they also use the browser's user agent, but that was easy to spoof.

Here is the .js in question: http://pastebin.com/f56fd608d. The code responsible for browser detection is at the top. Is there any way of changing the .js file before the site runs, or something similar, so I can eliminate the check?

Using the JavaScript console yields:

`>navigator.platform`
`Linux i686`

Evidently I changed the browser's user agent, but `navigator.platform` does not seem to take it's value from the user agent.

Maybe someone knows how to change the value returned by `navigator.platform`, because I hate running Windows under VirtualBox to use this site.

EDIT:
This could be of interest because Linux users might be artificially denied access to websites, and can do nothing about it.

Comment: what browser do you use?

Comment: I use Chrome and Firefox. Both take the platform information not from the User Agent, but from somewhere else. Probably it's built-in. I would use any browser under Linux that can provide a spoofed `navigator.platform`

Comment: Radu: All browsers except IE on all platforms support `__defineGetter__`. This is what you're looking for.

Comment: It's revolved here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1307013/mocking-a-useragent-in-javascript

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Since you can't directly set `navigator.platform`, you will have to be sneaky - create an object that behaves like `navigator`, replace its `platform`, then set `navigator` to it.

```
var fake_navigator = {};

for (var i in navigator) {
  fake_navigator[i] =  navigator[i];
}

fake_navigator.platform = 'MyOS';

navigator = fake_navigator;
```

If you execute this code before the document loads (using GreaseMonkey, an addon or a Chrome extension), then the page will see `navigator.platform` as `"MyOS"`.

Note: tested only in Chrome.

Comment: Yes, this is sneaky :)
Thank you for the help!

Comment: Actually, you can replace the platform getter. There is no platform setter so `navigator.platform = ...` doesn't do anything but Chrome supports the non-standard `__defineGetter__` method on all objects. Pre-alphas of Firefox support ECMAScript5's `Object.defineProperty` too.

Comment: I may be biased (because it's my answer) but I like defining a getter more, too.  But this works too, and it's what I would have thought of if the getter approach didn't exist.

Comment: This doesn't work anymore. The page doesn't see it. I used other method:  navigator.__defineGetter__('platform', function(){
  return( "Windows" );
 });  but this also doesn't work. Any help please appreciated !

Comment: I thought I'd install older Chrome from 2010 .. but there is a slight issue where to get tampermonkey for that :)

Comment: a list of platforms http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19877924/what-is-the-list-of-possible-values-for-navigator-platform-as-of-today, despite I cant make it work with tampermonkey, I think tampermonkey is buggy because it says no script is running, so it may work but I am not finding a way to test it.

Comment: oh, I ran syntax check and it failed for this line: `navigator = fake_navigator;` on tampermonkey; may be `navigator` is readonly?

Answer (score 20):

```
var fakePlatformGetter = function () {
  return "your fake platform";
};
if (Object.defineProperty) {
  Object.defineProperty(navigator, "platform", {
    get: fakePlatformGetter
  });
  Object.defineProperty(Navigator.prototype, "platform", {
    get: fakePlatformGetter
  });
} else if (Object.prototype.__defineGetter__) {
  navigator.__defineGetter__("platform", fakePlatformGetter);
  Navigator.prototype.__defineGetter__("platform", fakePlatformGetter);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Provided that the browser you're using supports `Object.defineProperty()` (it likely does), a more modern way of achieving the same goal is as follows:

```js
Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'platform', {
  value: 'my custom value',
  configurable: true // necessary to change value more than once
});
```

This allows you to set it to any custom value you want, and it also allows you to change it as many times as you want without needing to reload the page.

Answer (score 4):

about:config - > general.platform.override

Comment: this doesn't exist in Firefox 24 anymore. Which version did allow this ?

Answer (score 3):

For a Mozilla-based browser, [GreaseSpot / Code Snippets # Hijacking browser properties](http://wiki.greasespot.net/Code_snippets#Hijacking_browser_properties) demonstrates how it may be done.  This code may be injected from a [GreaseMonkey](http://www.greasespot.net/) script.

Comment: This looks promising, I'll try it. Thank you!

Comment: Link broken, poor answer.  See https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259   Here is an archived source, though: https://web.archive.org/web/20100122072411/http://wiki.greasespot.net/Code_snippets#Hijacking_browser_properties

Answer (score -2):

Attempting to change this property (at any time) in Firefox yields:

> Error: setting a property that has only a getter
>
> Source File: index.html
>
> Line: 1

So I think you will have a hard time.

I'd try to [contact the author](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/) about obtaining a fix.