# How to block youtube flash detection?

Tags: javascript

Using firefox greasemonkey or chrome tampermonkey, there are scripts that fake the window.navigator.plugins and window.navigator.mimeTypes. If you return undefined for those objects then most websites are fooled into thinking flash isn't installed even if it is there. Sites usually display message to install flash or start html5 player.

Youtube isn't tricked by userscript and still loads the flash player. How can you block youtube's flash detection?

Reference for faking navigator:
[How can I fool a site that looks at the JavaScript object 'navigator' to see that I'm not on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2166540/how-can-i-fool-a-site-that-looks-at-the-javascript-object-navigator-to-see-tha)

Comment: You should at how youtube detects flash is installed, and fool it, if you can.

Comment: I don't think SO is the appropriate place for such a question.  But, as a courtesy, you can add `html5=1` to the youtube url to get HTML5 player, e.g. _http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5-E_tikSXfc&html5=1_

Comment: it is an appropriate place IMO given coding a js script is required