# GWT Navigator.getPlatform() returns null

Tags: api, gwt

Strange but in my Production environment, I get value of GWT API `Navigator.getPlatform()` as Null.

On My Local Machine it works fine.

Any reason?

Answer (score 0):

Please note this property is sent by the browser and can thus be **faked**, just like user agent strings. Never rely on the navigator object to be completely accurate.

[Read more...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19877924/what-is-the-list-of-possible-values-for-navigator-platform-as-of-today)