# Call jquery method on desktop

Tags: jquery, responsive-design

I have the following jquery call on my website and I would only like it to be actioned if the visitor is using a desktop device (screen size over 767px). How can this be achieved?

**SCRIPT**

```
<script>$("#sidebar").stick_in_parent();</script>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia

Comment: Just FYI there's plenty of handheld devices which have a screen size over 767px. You probably want to check pixel ratio too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the window width, but keep in mind, there are handhelds with over 767px width. So this is not a "desktop check".

```
if( $(window).width() >= 767 )
    $("#sidebar").stick_in_parent();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use navigator.platform to get OS Name vs. using screen size.

[What is the list of possible values for navigator.platform as of today?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19877924/what-is-the-list-of-possible-values-for-navigator-platform-as-of-today)