# Find Windows devices using Javascript?

Tags: php

How to find Windowow devices using Javascript or jquery

Comment: What on earth is "Windowow"?

Comment: sorry its windows

Comment: tagged php and wants to use javascript?

Answer (score 0):

use 'navigator.platform' to check what platform you are using.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorID/platform

```
function isWindows() {
    return navigator.platform.indexOf('Win') > -1
}
// Maybe Try this on android deveices
function isAndroid() {
    return navigator.platform.indexOf('android') > -1
}
```

Comment: Do you know how to get all Android devices?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19877924/what-is-the-list-of-possible-values-for-navigator-platform-as-of-today
here you can find a list od platform.

Comment: Thas a 3 year ago question.

Comment: that's right. any different?

Comment: @ monkianer,there are updated devices.

Comment: If you have that kind of device in the hand, then you can use 'navigator.platform' to check what's string returned. If you can tell me what kind of device is not detected maybe I can try to figure it out.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148149/discussion-between-monkianer-and-chris-harris).