# How to get OS version in PC in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to find OS version of a user's device. For the mobile device, I know how it's done and had successfully done that for ios and android but I need to find PC's OS versions too

> Suppose I am a user who is using Ubuntu 16.04 then I need to get this
>   from my script but right now I get `"Linux"` as OS

I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9514179/how-to-find-the-operating-system-version-using-javascript) too. but `oscpu` key is not provided in the navigator

```js
var user = {}
user.device = {};

function findBrowserDetails() {
  user.device = {};
  var unknown = '-';

  // screen
  var screenSize = '';
  if (screen.width) {
    width = (screen.width) ? screen.width : '';
    height = (screen.height) ? screen.height : '';
    screenSize += '' + width + " x " + height;
  }
  console.log("What i get from above link is--", navigator);
  // browser
  var nVer = navigator.appVersion;
  var nAgt = navigator.userAgent || navigator.vendor || window.opera;

  var browser = navigator.appName;
  var version = '' + parseFloat(navigator.appVersion);
  var majorVersion = parseInt(navigator.appVersion, 10);
  var nameOffset, verOffset, ix;

  // Opera
  if ((verOffset = nAgt.indexOf('Opera')) != -1) {
    browser = 'Opera';
    version = nAgt.substring(verOffset + 6);
    if ((verOffset = nAgt.indexOf('Version')) != -1) {
      version = nAgt.substring(verOffset + 8);
    }
  }
  // Opera Next
  if ((verOffset = nAgt.indexOf('OPR')) != -1) {
    browser = 'Opera';
    version = nAgt.substring(verOffset + 4);
  }
  // Edge
  else if ((verOffset = nAgt.indexOf('Edge')) != -1) {
    browser = 'Microsoft Edge';
    version = nAgt.substring(verOffset + 5);
  }
  // MSIE
  else if ((verOffset = nAgt.indexOf('MSIE')) != -1) {
    browser = 'Microsoft Internet Explorer';
    version = nAgt.substring(verOffset + 5);
  }
  // Chrome
  else if ((verOffset = nAgt.indexOf('Chrome')) != -1) {
    browser = 'Chrome';
    version = nAgt.substring(verOffset + 7);
  }
  // Safari
  else if ((verOffset = nAgt.indexOf('Safari')) != -1) {
    browser = 'Safari';
    version = nAgt.substring(verOffset + 7);
    if ((verOffset = nAgt.indexOf('Version')) != -1) {
      version = nAgt.substring(verOffset + 8);
    }
  }
  // Firefox
  else if ((verOffset = nAgt.indexOf('Firefox')) != -1) {
    browser = 'Firefox';
    version = nAgt.substring(verOffset + 8);
  }
  // MSIE 11+
  else if (nAgt.indexOf('Trident/') != -1) {
    browser = 'Microsoft Internet Explorer';
    version = nAgt.substring(nAgt.indexOf('rv:') + 3);
  }
  // Other browsers
  else if ((nameOffset = nAgt.lastIndexOf(' ') + 1) < (verOffset = nAgt.lastIndexOf('/'))) {
    browser = nAgt.substring(nameOffset, verOffset);
    version = nAgt.substring(verOffset + 1);
    if (browser.toLowerCase() == browser.toUpperCase()) {
      browser = navigator.appName;
    }
  }
  // trim the version string
  if ((ix = version.indexOf(';')) != -1) version = version.substring(0, ix);
  if ((ix = version.indexOf(' ')) != -1) version = version.substring(0, ix);
  if ((ix = version.indexOf(')')) != -1) version = version.substring(0, ix);

  majorVersion = parseInt('' + version, 10);
  if (isNaN(majorVersion)) {
    version = '' + parseFloat(navigator.appVersion);
    majorVersion = parseInt(navigator.appVersion, 10);
  }

  // mobile version
  var mobile = /Mobile|mini|Fennec|Android|iP(ad|od|hone)/.test(nVer);

  // system
  var os = unknown;
  var clientStrings = [{
    s: 'Windows 10',
    r: /(Windows 10.0|Windows NT 10.0)/
  }, {
    s: 'Windows 8.1',
    r: /(Windows 8.1|Windows NT 6.3)/
  }, {
    s: 'Windows 8',
    r: /(Windows 8|Windows NT 6.2)/
  }, {
    s: 'Windows 7',
    r: /(Windows 7|Windows NT 6.1)/
  }, {
    s: 'Windows Vista',
    r: /Windows NT 6.0/
  }, {
    s: 'Windows Server 2003',
    r: /Windows NT 5.2/
  }, {
    s: 'Windows XP',
    r: /(Windows NT 5.1|Windows XP)/
  }, {
    s: 'Windows 2000',
    r: /(Windows NT 5.0|Windows 2000)/
  }, {
    s: 'Windows ME',
    r: /(Win 9x 4.90|Windows ME)/
  }, {
    s: 'Windows 98',
    r: /(Windows 98|Win98)/
  }, {
    s: 'Windows 95',
    r: /(Windows 95|Win95|Windows_95)/
  }, {
    s: 'Windows NT 4.0',
    r: /(Windows NT 4.0|WinNT4.0|WinNT|Windows NT)/
  }, {
    s: 'Windows CE',
    r: /Windows CE/
  }, {
    s: 'Windows 3.11',
    r: /Win16/
  }, {
    s: 'Android',
    r: /Android/
  }, {
    s: 'Open BSD',
    r: /OpenBSD/
  }, {
    s: 'Sun OS',
    r: /SunOS/
  }, {
    s: 'Linux',
    r: /(Linux|X11)/
  }, {
    s: 'iOS',
    r: /(iPhone|iPad|iPod)/
  }, {
    s: 'Mac OS X',
    r: /Mac OS X/
  }, {
    s: 'Mac OS',
    r: /(MacPPC|MacIntel|Mac_PowerPC|Macintosh)/
  }, {
    s: 'QNX',
    r: /QNX/
  }, {
    s: 'UNIX',
    r: /UNIX/
  }, {
    s: 'BeOS',
    r: /BeOS/
  }, {
    s: 'OS/2',
    r: /OS\/2/
  }, {
    s: 'Search Bot',
    r: /(nuhk|Googlebot|Yammybot|Openbot|Slurp|MSNBot|Ask Jeeves\/Teoma|ia_archiver)/
  }];
  for (var id in clientStrings) {
    var cs = clientStrings[id];
    if (cs.r.test(nAgt)) {
      os = cs.s;
      break;
    }
  }

  var osVersion = unknown;

  if (/Windows/.test(os)) {
    osVersion = /Windows (.*)/.exec(os)[1];
    os = 'Windows';
  }

  switch (os) {
    case 'Mac OS X':
      osVersion = /Mac OS X (10[\.\_\d]+)/.exec(nAgt)[1];
      break;

    case 'Android':
      osVersion = /Android ([\.\_\d]+)/.exec(nAgt)[1];
      break;

    case 'iOS':
      osVersion = /OS (\d+)_(\d+)_?(\d+)?/.exec(nVer);
      osVersion = osVersion[1] + '.' + osVersion[2] + '.' + (osVersion[3] | 0);
      break;
  }

  window.jscd = {
    screen: screenSize,
    browser: browser,
    browserVersion: version,
    browserMajorVersion: majorVersion,
    mobile: mobile,
    os: os,
    osVersion: osVersion,
  };

  user.device = window.jscd;
  //detect device type
  if (/windows phone/i.test(nAgt)) {
    user.device.deviceType = "Windows Phone";
  } else if (/android/i.test(nAgt)) {
    user.device.deviceType = "Android";
  } else if (/iPad|iPhone|iPod/.test(nAgt) && !window.MSStream) {
    user.device.deviceType = "iOS";
  } else {
    user.device.deviceType = "web";
  }
  console.log("This is what so far i fetched", user.device)
}
findBrowserDetails();
```

Comment: navigator.platform will give you the OS version

Comment: You could use `navigator.oscpu` to get full version details of OS. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/oscpu

Comment: `navigator.oscpu` is not supported by Chrome as shown in the Browser Compatibility  table.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/oscpu#Browser_compatibility

Comment: yep @SamiAhmedSiddiqui you are right

Comment: navigator.oscpu is undefined in chrome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
navigator.platform
```

this will give you the OS name like 
[image]

**UPDATE**

```
var OSName="Unknown OS";
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Win")!=-1) OSName="Windows";
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Mac")!=-1) OSName="MacOS";
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("X11")!=-1) OSName="UNIX";
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Linux")!=-1) OSName="Linux";

document.write('Your OS: '+OSName);
```

On your system, this script yields the following result: 
Your OS: Linux
(To get more detailed OS information, your script should perform a more sophisticated analysis of `navigator.appVersion` or `navigator.userAgent`, but the idea would be the same.)

Comment: thanks for your response. But can't I get version name as I described in my question i.e Ubuntu 16.04 something like that?

Comment: nope I guess not.. see this for more detail [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19877924/what-is-the-list-of-possible-values-for-navigator-platform-as-of-today)

Comment: you simply can't rely on `navigator` object because it is send by user agent thus it can be faked :)

Comment: So I suppose I have to settle with navigator.platform then :(

Comment: yeah :) I have used in application it's fine

Answer (score 1):

You can get the version number of OS from the `navigator.userAgent` but you can't get the version name as per my knowledge till yet.

If you like to get the version number so this article may helps you with it:
https://medium.com/creative-technology-concepts-code/detect-device-browser-and-version-using-javascript-8b511906745

Here is complete code which provide you the OS Name, OS Version, Browser Name and and Browser Version.

```js
(function () {
    'use strict';
    
    var module = {
        options: [],
        header: [navigator.platform, navigator.userAgent, navigator.appVersion, navigator.vendor, window.opera],
        dataos: [
            { name: 'Windows Phone', value: 'Windows Phone', version: 'OS' },
            { name: 'Windows', value: 'Win', version: 'NT' },
            { name: 'iPhone', value: 'iPhone', version: 'OS' },
            { name: 'iPad', value: 'iPad', version: 'OS' },
            { name: 'Kindle', value: 'Silk', version: 'Silk' },
            { name: 'Android', value: 'Android', version: 'Android' },
            { name: 'PlayBook', value: 'PlayBook', version: 'OS' },
            { name: 'BlackBerry', value: 'BlackBerry', version: '/' },
            { name: 'Macintosh', value: 'Mac', version: 'OS X' },
            { name: 'Linux', value: 'Linux', version: 'rv' },
            { name: 'Palm', value: 'Palm', version: 'PalmOS' }
        ],
        databrowser: [
            { name: 'Chrome', value: 'Chrome', version: 'Chrome' },
            { name: 'Firefox', value: 'Firefox', version: 'Firefox' },
            { name: 'Safari', value: 'Safari', version: 'Version' },
            { name: 'Internet Explorer', value: 'MSIE', version: 'MSIE' },
            { name: 'Opera', value: 'Opera', version: 'Opera' },
            { name: 'BlackBerry', value: 'CLDC', version: 'CLDC' },
            { name: 'Mozilla', value: 'Mozilla', version: 'Mozilla' }
        ],
        init: function () {
            var agent = this.header.join(' '),
                os = this.matchItem(agent, this.dataos),
                browser = this.matchItem(agent, this.databrowser);
            
            return { os: os, browser: browser };
        },
        matchItem: function (string, data) {
            var i = 0,
                j = 0,
                html = '',
                regex,
                regexv,
                match,
                matches,
                version;
            
            for (i = 0; i < data.length; i += 1) {
                regex = new RegExp(data[i].value, 'i');
                match = regex.test(string);
                if (match) {
                    regexv = new RegExp(data[i].version + '[- /:;]([\\d._]+)', 'i');
                    matches = string.match(regexv);
                    version = '';
                    if (matches) { if (matches[1]) { matches = matches[1]; } }
                    if (matches) {
                        matches = matches.split(/[._]+/);
                        for (j = 0; j < matches.length; j += 1) {
                            if (j === 0) {
                                version += matches[j] + '.';
                            } else {
                                version += matches[j];
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        version = '0';
                    }
                    return {
                        name: data[i].name,
                        version: parseFloat(version)
                    };
                }
            }
            return { name: 'unknown', version: 0 };
        }
    };
    
    var e = module.init(),
        debug = '';
    
    debug += 'os.name = ' + e.os.name + '<br/>';
    debug += 'os.version = ' + e.os.version + '<br/>';
    debug += 'browser.name = ' + e.browser.name + '<br/>';
    debug += 'browser.version = ' + e.browser.version + '<br/>';
 
    document.getElementById('log').innerHTML = debug;
}());
```

```html
<div id="log"></div>
```

Above code is copy and pasted from here: https://jsfiddle.net/kmturley/Gd6c8/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=Gd6c8

If you still like to get the OS Name so either you can get this through some kind of library (i don't if any library exist) or you can define key value pair with version number and version name hardcoding in it but that is definitely the hectic job and may not suits you.

Comment: thanks for your response. But can't I get version name as I described in my question i.e Ubuntu 16.04 something like that?

Comment: @the_ultimate_developer you can get the OS Version number by using the above code. I don't think that is there any way by which you can get the version name from the JS until or unless you may some library which may provide this or create a list in which you may define the version name across version number but that's a hectic job.

Comment: Thanks for your information! have upvoted for your efforts :)