# How to detect mobile or desktop and not get "cheated" by chrome dev tools

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm trying to detect when the user uses a mobile device on my application.

Usually, we will detect by using a user-agent or touchable screen, but chrome mobile mode in the dev tools changes both of those.

Do you have any idea how can i detect mobile or desktop and not get cheated by chrome dev tools?

Comment: Because of the range of possible devices types, its not really relevant to distinguish mobile/desktop (i.e. is a tablet a mobile or a desktop?).   It depends on why you want to distinguish, but usually its a for layout (so screen size/aspect ratio is usually what you need to look for), or for input capabilities (and some devices are hybrid touch/pointer capable).

Comment: It doesn't really matter to me mobile/tablet, the main thing I'm looking for is (Desktop/ no Desktop). 
In ratio search I will aslo get "cheated" because the mobile mode in chrome using real device sizes

Comment: You aren't being 'cheated', this has more to do with the reality that there is no longer a distinction between the type of device but its capabilities.  The User Agent was only ever a hint, and its quite common for robots to misidentify as browsers.  Perhaps if you can describe what you want to do with the distinction it would help?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of going for type of device, you can check for operating system. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19877924/what-is-the-list-of-possible-values-for-navigator-platform-as-of-today) is a list of possible values you can use.

```
windowsPlatforms = ['Win32', 'Win64', 'Windows', 'WinCE'];
android = "Android";
typeOfOS = window.navigator.platform;

if (windowsPlatforms.includes(typeOfOS)) {
     //do for windows
} else if(typeOfOS === android){
     //do for android
}
```

Comment: Useful to know, but not recommended.  Feature detection is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in css. You can use the @media to see if the screen size is smaller than that usually desktops have and by this you will be able to make your application responsive. Take a look at this code:

```css
body {
  --background-image: url('https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/vertical-banner-template-hands-typing-computer-office-supplies-distance-education-e-learning-obtaining-university-156390588.jpg');
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-image: var(--background-image);
  background-size: 100vw 100vh;
  z-index: -1000;
}

#submit-form {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  height: 180px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 2px dashed;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
  z-index: 1000;
}

#email-input {
  height: 30px;
  width: 220px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

#submit-button {
  height: 30px;
  width: 80px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  border: 1px dashed;
}

@media all and (min-width: 1000px) {
  body {
    background-image: url('https://img.freepik.com/free-vector/online-education-students-view-lessons-through-mobile-devices-during-distance-learning_178888-361.jpg?w=2000');
  }
  #submit-form {
    height: 250px;
    width: 500px;
  }
  #email-input {
    height: 50px;
    width: 300px;
    border-radius: 10px;
  }
}
```

Here I am styling the sites for mobile devices first, and then, I am checking if the user is on a desktop and if he is, I am making the website responsive again.

This was for the styling part, but, what if you want to detect it in JavaScript?

You can use a simple function for this:

```js
function findUserDevice() {
  const isOnMobile = false;

  if(window.innerWidth < window.innerHeight) {
    isOnMobile = true;
  }
  return isOnMobile;
}
```

This is what I usually use, hope this was helpful!

Comment: That is not very reliable since resolution of phones each year overlaps more and more with desktops, not to mention tablets.

Comment: That's true, a better solution is to know exactly which device the user is using. This is what usually works for me by updating it from time to time. However, it will be quite hard to optimize it for each type of device...

Comment: @GJeswin No, that is not a better solution at all.  The best solution is to adjust for the specific parameters you depend upon, such as input method (touch vs mouse, perhaps also primary input method), or viewport size, or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it without checking the OS, or the window size is through feature detection, by checking the touch events, like this:

```
const isMobile = 'ontouchstart' in window || navigator.maxTouchPoints > 0;
```

This will return a boolean to whether the user is on Mobile or not, wihthout being tricked using desktop view on mobile.