# How to prevent Chrome Dev Tools Detection?

Tags: android, google-chrome, mobile, google-chrome-devtools, mobile-browser

I just saw this article.
[How to detect mobile or desktop and not get "cheated" by chrome dev tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72675075/how-to-detect-mobile-or-desktop-and-not-get-cheated-by-chrome-dev-tools)

It shows some special ways to detect the browser is real mobile device or Chrome Dev Tools.
My question is how to prevent this so that act like a real mobile browser.

This is the code to detect Chrome Dev Tools.

```
windowsPlatforms = ['Win32', 'Win64', 'Windows', 'WinCE'];
android = "Android";
typeOfOS = window.navigator.platform;

if (windowsPlatforms.includes(typeOfOS)) {
     //do for windows
} else if(typeOfOS === android){
     //do for android
}
```

In the article above, there are some other ways to detect Chrome Dev Tools.

Is there any method or tools that fully emulate the real mobile device?

Answer (score 0):

Try look at this, there is many ways and libraries that can help you with this

https://dev.to/composite/a-simple-way-to-detect-devtools-2ag0

Comment: My question was how to prevent Devtools Detection, not how to detect DevTools.