# How can I spoof the navigator.platform property in Safari? - Safari Extension

Tags: javascript, macos, safari, safari-extension, navigator

I would like to spoof the navigator.platform property in Safari so that I can make websites think that I am running on a Windows architecture. I created a Safari extension that attempts to do this. The plugin simply contains a blank "global.html" file and a file "spoof.js" that is injected as a "start script" (basically it executes on every page before the content of that page loads). The contents of spoof.js are:

```
//Copied from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2166540/how-can-i-fool-a-site-that-looks-at-the-javascript-object-navigator-to-see-tha
new_navigator = {};
for (var i in navigator) {
    new_navigator[i] = navigator[i];
}

new_navigator.platform = 'Windows';

navigator = new_navigator;
//alert(navigator.platform);
```

If I uncomment the last line the alert box will say "Windows" every time I load a page, but when I test the extension using [this page](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_nav_platform.asp) the website always reads the navigator.platform property as "MacIntel".

I found this excerpt in Apple's [Safari extension developer's guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/Tools/Conceptual/SafariExtensionGuide/InjectingScripts/InjectingScripts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009977-CH6-SW1).

> Injected scripts have an implied namespace—you don’t have to worry
>   about your variable or function names conflicting with those of the
>   website author, nor can a website author call functions in your
>   extension. In other words, injected scripts and scripts included in
>   the webpage run in isolated worlds, with no access to each other’s
>   functions or data.

Does this mean that there is no way that I can edit the navigator item with a Safari extension? Is there any way that I can set the navigator object using an extension?

Comment: Setting the UA string is not the same as setting the navigator.platform object. Check this website: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_nav_platform.asp

You'll see that no matter what you set the UA string to, the platform doesn't change.

Comment: This is an answer specifically for Chrome extensions, but since the same extension model applies, and both are WebKit-based, I think that the answer fully applies to your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23202136/changing-navigator-useragent-using-chrome-extension/23456845#23456845