# How to change browser User-Agent Header with javaScript?

Tags: javascript, browser, user-agent

Following code changes property printed (when accessed through javaScript) by browser console and not the actual Use-Agent string sent with the header.

```
Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'userAgent', {
    get: function () { return 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; 
    rv:28.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/28.0)'; }
});
```

Comment: _A Navigator object can be retrieved using the **read-only** window.navigator property._ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator

Comment: However https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2166540/how-can-i-fool-a-site-that-looks-at-the-javascript-object-navigator-to-see-tha

Comment: Firefox and Safari just let you use `XHR.setRequestHeader('User-Agent', 'whatever')`. Chrome on the other hand throws an error...

Comment: This is now allowed, see my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't possible from the page itself.  The user agent string (as sent in the HTTP request headers) can only be changed via browser extension or browser configuration.

Comment: I trust you are right but maybe you could provide a link to so something that confirms your statement

Answer (score 5):

This is now possible to do, see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Forbidden_header_name
You can use ‘ XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader(User-Agent, value)’

Comment: Although it should be possible, it does seems like Chromium is behaving like old IE - they make there own rules. I tested both Chrome and Edge - User-Agent is being ignored and controlled by said browsers.

Comment: Chromium responds with this in the console: Refused to set unsafe header "User-Agent".