# Is there any way that I can set a user agent by using HTML or JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, discord, user-agent

So I am working on a project that access a discord bot using a token in web browsers
But recently, discord has changed their policy of bot requests, that make us have to manually change the user agent setting in the developer tools.
Now I am wondering that is there any way that I can override the user agent setting of browser in JavaScript or HTML?

I have tried the method at [here](https://gist.github.com/thorsten/148812e9cc4fb6a19215ce22afd4e5a8)
For instance, after pasting the code:

```
setUserAgent(window, "BDP (http://example.com), v0.0.1)");
```

And it seems that it no loger work so I tried again with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23248525/setting-a-custom-useragent-in-html-or-javascript)
For instance:

```js
Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'userAgent', {
    get: function () { return 'BDP (http://example.com), v0.0.1)'; }
});
```

But none of the method above helps me. Is there any way that I can override the user agent of browser?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change browser User-Agent Header with javaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58005954/how-to-change-browser-user-agent-header-with-javascript)

Comment: [navigator.userAgent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/userAgent) is a `read-only` property.

Comment: @Ivar  I tried `XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader('userAgent', customUserAgent)` and its a no-go - or am I using it the wrong way?  
If so, can u give an example for that?  
Thanks!

Comment: @YueYue What browser are you using? Did you check the note on [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Forbidden_header_name)?

Comment: @Ivar I am using Opera, and firefox wont work too...

Comment: After reading the MDN page @Ivar has linked, it looks like you could set `User-Agent` header with XHR/Fetch requests, notice the spelling. There's also a mention of a Chromium bug, and it's still listed as Forbidden header name at [its documentation page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent), though.

Answer (score -3):

Please try using this code.. navigator.useragent returns the browser name..

```js
if((navigator.userAgent.indexOf("BrowserName"))
{
    //write some code
}
```

Comment: You seem to have confused "set" with "read"