# How to specify User Agent String (UA) - on a per request / iFrame basis?

Tags: iframe, http-headers, xss, user-agent, xmlhttprequest

Is there a simple way to specify the UA string for a particular http request, frame or iFrame within a single page?

For example, the main request to the server would come from...

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7) AppleWebKit/534.48.3 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1 Safari/534.48.3
```

and a second request, whether to the originating (your) or another (XSS), from an iFrame or XHR, etc. would identify itself as

```
Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone OS 4_2_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/533.17.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.0.2 Mobile/8C148a Safari/6533.18.5
```

I realize this is possible via myriad a proxy mechanism... but all such solutions involve convoluted session and cookie manipulation, etc..  Is this possible from a direct page-authorer's perspective and toolbox (ie. JS, page headers, even server configs, etc?)

Comment: I think I sorta answered my own question in a [response to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5426899/creating-a-proxy-to-spoof-iphone-user-agent-in-php/6630823#6630823) "You could use a PHP class, such as Ben Alman's Simple PHP Proxy.. It let's you redirect cross-domain URL's in a variety of ways, including the following method to "change up" your User Agent...."

Answer (score 0):

No, a web page cannot change what user agent the browser sends.
The exception to this is if you use flash to make requests. Then it'll use flash's user agent.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to change the user-agent when you are using JS to send requests.
Note that it is generally not a good idea to change it, as firewalls / load balancers might get confused if an authenticated user suddenly changes user-agent string, and might consider it a session injection attack...

Comment: gggeek, how do you do that? Please answer my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6995311/how-to-spoof-the-user-agent-in-a-get-request-using-javascript