# How can I spoof the user agent of a JavaScript GET request?

Tags: javascript, user-agent, http-get, spoofing

How can I spoof the user agent of a JavaScript GET request? [setRequestHeader](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-setrequestheader-method) with `User-Agent` isn't allowed:

```
xmlHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("User-Agent", "...");
```

Comment: I hop that this wont work you shuld not be able to tell the server that your in an other env then you are from a client.

Comment: You can and you should be able to tell the server that you're in a different enviroment than you actually are - and plenty of browsers do allow you o change your User-Agent string. That beeing said I do not know of such a mechanism controllable from JavaScript.

Comment: On the client-side browser, I need to get the webpage source from a server that performs server-side browser sniffing. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do this in a half-decent browser because of security issues surrounding it. You don't want XSS scripts to be changing request headers and running rampant on your site.

However I believe there's a workaround in [IE if you use VBScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms766589.aspx):

```
MyHttp.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "MyCustomUser"
```

The alternative is to have a web page on your site dedicated to forwarding a GET request, changing the appropriate headers as necessary.

Answer (score 5):

In short: You can't due to built-in cross-domain limitations.

One way "around" that was to write a proxy-webservice and let the server spoof whatever headers you need spoofed.