# Change mobile browser's userAgent in order to play all youtube iframe videos?

Tags: javascript, cordova, iframe, youtube, user-agent

Is there any way I can change a user's userAgent through Javascript. I use the youtube iframe API and most of the videos are blocked on mobile. Is there any workaround for this? (I have tried the API's embedded and syndication settings with no success). Moreover, I have tried this site on mobile (http://www.youtubedoubler.com) and all youtube videos are accessible regardless of it being embedded.
Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set navigator userAgent?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18960908/how-to-set-navigator-useragent)

Comment: there is an android plugin for changing the user agent, google it

Comment: That will only work if it concerns your own phone. If you are a web designer and want to fake a different uA on the phones of your web site visitors, that won't work.

Comment: benjipelletier , I have a question. Can you tell me the browser or the userAgent which let me play youtube in banned countries(where youtube is banned).