# TypeError: WindowActiveXObject is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine, user-agent

An attempt to mock the userAgent property for unit testing:

```javascript
Object.defineProperty(navigator, "userAgent", {
    get: function () {
        return "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; rv:11.0) like Gecko"; // customized user agent
    }
});
```

or

```javascript
navigator.__defineGetter__('userAgent', function(){
    return 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; rv:11.0) like Gecko'; // customized user agent
});
```

the following error is thrown:

```
TypeError: WindowActiveXObject is not a constructor
```

Is there any other way to mock the userAgent within Jasmine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `navigator.userAgent` is a read only attribute according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorID/userAgent) & this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18960908/how-to-set-navigator-useragent).
- Therefor you'll not be able to spy on it as you'll receive an error stating no writable method found.
- However you could override the userAgent and mock it accordingly from the [before & after blocks](https://jasmine.github.io/2.5/introduction#section-Setup_and_Teardown) in jasmine unit test.

Here is [one way](https://jsfiddle.net/randomfifaguy/w1usxb7x/14/) to do this:

```
var testFunc = function(name) {
  return name + " " + navigator.userAgent;
}

describe('test useragent', function() {
  var defaultUA = navigator.userAgent;
  beforeEach(function() {
    navigator.__defineGetter__('userAgent', function() {
      return 'foo' // customized user agent
    });
    console.log("Changing UA to: " + navigator.userAgent)
  });

  afterEach(function() {
    navigator.__defineGetter__('userAgent', function() {
      return defaultUA // customized user agent
    });
    console.log("Resetting it to: " + navigator.userAgent)
  });

  it('test UA', function() {
    var val = testFunc("Bruce");
    console.log(val)
    expect(val).toEqual("Bruce foo");
  });
});
```