# How do i mock and customise the values of a function imported from a npm package using Jest?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, mocking, jestjs

I use `isMobileOnly` from "react-device-detect" npm package in my React component say(SampleComponent.js).

I would like to customize the return value of `isMobileOnly` in my jest unit tests.

I have tried Jest manual mocks as mentioned in the link below:
https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks

But it does not seem to work for me.

I have also tried:
jest's mockImplementation
jest's mockImplementationOnce
jest's spyOn

```
import {isMobileOnly} from 'react-device-detect;
```

In my jest unit tests, i would like to mock the function `isMobileOnly` in such a way that i should be able to customize its return value to "true". The default value is "false".

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me.

In your test file, add this: **import * as deviceDetect from 'react-device-detect';**

then you can change things like: **deviceDetect.isMobileOnly = true;**

eg.

```
import * as deviceDetect from 'react-device-detect'; //<--important

it.only('clicking on myAccount redirects to /user/myAccount', () => {

        ///make sure this is before mount or shallow
        deviceDetect.isMobileOnly = true; //<--important

        component = mount(<Provider store={store}><Sidebar history={mockedHistory} /></Provider>);
        component.find('[test-id="myAccount"]').first().simulate('click');
        expect(mockedHistory.push).toHaveBeenCalledWith('/user/myAccount');
    });
```

Comment: Does this require automocks to be enabled?

Answer (score 1):

Finally! I figured it out myself after hours of struggle. Here is what i did:

1. Created `__mocks__` folder in the same level as node_modules directory where the package "react-device-detect" is available. Note: smaller case is important for `__mocks__`.
2. Created a file named "react-device-detect.js" within the `__mocks__` folder.
3. Added the following code in it:

   ```
   const deviceDetect = jest.genMockFromModule('react-device-detect');
   deviceDetect.isMobileOnly = true;
   module.exports = deviceDetect;
   ```
4. Within the test file, i imported the "isMobileOnly" as i did in the original 
   component:

   ```
   import { isMobileOnly } from 'react-device-detect';
   ```
5. Now, i can change value of "deviceDetect.isMobileOnly" to true or false in the 
   mocked file as per the unit test case's need .

For more details, refer the official documentation here https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks

Thanks @Roman for reaching out!

Comment: Do you not get a module not found when you're trying to use `deviceDetect ` in your test file? What you're doing looks right but it's not working for me.

Answer (score 1):

I use the `" import * as  deviceDetect"` answer, it worked but I ran into an issue because of typescript and the readonly property of isMobile.

So this solution worked for me :

```
Object.defineProperty(reactDeviceDetect, 'isIOS', { get: () => true });
```

as describe [here](https://dev.to/artnerdnet/testing-react-device-detect-with-react-testing-library-and-jest-3kn6)

I hope that help!

Answer (score 0):

You can possibly override the User Agent for testing purposes so `react-device-detect` package will identify it like You need, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1307088/4861449)'s how to do that.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18960908/how-to-set-navigator-useragent) topic should also be helpful.