# Setting a custom userAgent in HTML or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, get, user-agent

Is there any way to do this? I'm trying to send a GET request to a website, but I want to customize my UserAgent. Is there any way to do this in pure HTML and JavaScript? I'd like it to all execute locally.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mocking a useragent in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1307013/mocking-a-useragent-in-javascript)

Answer (score 19):

This is working for me.

```
Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'userAgent', {
    get: function () { return 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:28.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/28.0)'; }
});
```

It is an updated version of code4coffee's answer as `Object.prototype.__defineGetter__()` is deprecated: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/__defineGetter__

Comment: This is not working for me right now in Windows Google Chrome Version 78.0.3904.108 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: @Ryan because this header is now read-only

Answer (score 10):

You can programmatically do this in Javascript (this example mocks up Firefox):

```
navigator.__defineGetter__('userAgent', function () {
    return "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:28.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/28.0)"
});
navigator.__defineGetter__('appName', function () {
    return "Netscape"
});
```

You can then view the changes in the console via (and of course check these via Javascript):

```
navigator.userAgent
navigator.appName
```

Here's an example of a test that should work (using Jasmine):

```
describe("isUserAgentInternetExplorer", function () {
    it("should return false for Firefox", function () {
        navigator.__defineGetter__('userAgent', function () {
            return "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:28.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/28.0)"
        });
        navigator.__defineGetter__('appName', function () {
            return "Netscape"
        });
        //your code here...
        expect(...your code here...).toEqual(false);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 5):

## 2022

You are not allowed to modify the following headers, according to [Fetch WHATWG spec](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#forbidden-header-name).
And in 2022 all the evergreen browsers have implemented this requirement.

```
`Accept-Charset`
`Accept-Encoding`
`Access-Control-Request-Headers`
`Access-Control-Request-Method`
`Connection`
`Content-Length`
`Cookie`
`Cookie2`
`Date`
`DNT`
`Expect`
`Host`
`Keep-Alive`
`Origin`
`Referer`
`TE`
`Trailer`
`Transfer-Encoding`
`Upgrade`
`Via`
```

As well as headers, starting with `proxy-` or `sec-`.

`These are forbidden so the user agent remains in full control over them.`

Answer (score -1):

If you are using a XMLHttpRequest you can set a custom Request Header like:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(...);
xhr.setRequestHeader("User-Agent","test");
```

Comment: I'm sorry but Chromium complains:
Refused to set unsafe header "User-Agent

Comment: Idem with FF31.

Answer (score -5):

You will never change a user Agent in HTML, html is the message not messenger.

Indeed you can do it with a javascript code, but it's dangerous if you ever deploy it in production.

It's far safer to use an agent switcher:

https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/addon/user-agent-switcher/

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/user-agent-switcher-for-c/djflhoibgkdhkhhcedjiklpkjnoahfmg