# How to change user-agent using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, user-agent

I am using Google OAuth to authenticate, but it fails for iPhone and says "disallowed user-agent".

Is there a way to change the user-agent using JavaScript?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [403 Error - Thats an error. Error: disallowed\_useragent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40591090/403-error-thats-an-error-error-disallowed-useragent)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting a custom userAgent in HTML or JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23248525/setting-a-custom-useragent-in-html-or-javascript)