# Can I make a get request look like that of a browsers?

Tags: javascript, get, request, fetch

Is it possible to make a GET request look like it was sent from a browser? I know that you can set useragents, but I am wondering if there is anything else that I can change. Thanks! (in javascript)

Comment: Try playing with the headers. I'm not sure about the frontend, but in Nodejs it should be quit simply because you make the whole request. In the frontend, the browser making the request.

Comment: @NirGofman  already did,  and it didnt seem to do much. If you know how to do this, please answer

Comment: Maybe this would be helpful [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23248525/setting-a-custom-useragent-in-html-or-javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23248525/setting-a-custom-useragent-in-html-or-javascript)