# What headers should I add to a fetch request to make it look like it was sent from a browser?

Tags: javascript, node.js, fetch-api

If I make a fetch request in Node.js, and I want to make the fetch request look as browser-like as possible, what headers should I set besides the obvious User Agent header?

Similar to this question: [Can I make a get request look like that of a browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65064409/can-i-make-a-get-request-look-like-that-of-a-browsers) but a little more specific (I only care about setting headers).

Comment: Make the request from your browser and capture the headers. You can even export the request as `fetch` code (right-click on the request in dev-tools and select _Copy -> Copy as fetch_)

Answer (score -2):

Header should be like this:

```
{
User-Agent: Firefox,
 //your rest header
}
```

*User-Agent shows the agent the user is using to communicate with the server.* I have shown one in the picture in the link. Image of Wikipedia request on my computer. See the red highlighted area. Other information have been obfuscated as I am Wikipedia writer and to protect this account:

[image: Wikipedia image] .