# How can I change viewport with while being in desktop view?

Tags: javascript, css

I want to change my app viewport while being in desktop view like this website has this functionality where you can click on "mobile" or "tabled" or "desktop" view: https://pro.chakra-ui.com/components/application/shells

Answer (score 1):

Something like this

```js
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.querySelector(".myDiv").classList.toggle("mobile");
});
```

```css
div.mobile {
  width: 8em;
  height: 14em;
}
```

```html
<button id="vp">Change</button>
<div class="myDiv">
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Scelerisque mauris pellentesque pulvinar pellentesque habitant morbi tristique. Odio ut enim blandit volutpat maecenas volutpat
    blandit aliquam. Id semper risus in hendrerit gravida rutrum. Nunc scelerisque viverra mauris in aliquam sem fringilla ut morbi. Vestibulum sed arcu non odio euismod lacinia at quis risus. Facilisis volutpat est velit egestas dui id ornare arcu odio.
    Dignissim suspendisse in est ante in nibh mauris cursus. Eget mi proin sed libero enim sed faucibus turpis. Risus nullam eget felis eget. Risus commodo viverra maecenas accumsan lacus. Faucibus nisl tincidunt eget nullam non nisi est. Eleifend mi
    in nulla posuere sollicitudin aliquam. Id consectetur purus ut faucibus pulvinar elementum integer enim. Et leo duis ut diam quam nulla porttitor massa. Cras semper auctor neque vitae. Magna sit amet purus gravida quis blandit turpis. Egestas diam
    in arcu cursus. Amet mattis vulputate enim nulla aliquet porttitor lacus luctus. Commodo viverra maecenas accumsan lacus vel facilisis volutpat est. Morbi tincidunt augue interdum velit euismod in pellentesque massa placerat. Sed arcu non odio euismod
    lacinia. Pellentesque pulvinar pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus. Mi bibendum neque egestas congue. Justo nec ultrices dui sapien eget mi proin sed libero. Senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Nisi scelerisque eu ultrices
    vitae auctor eu augue ut. Vitae et leo duis ut diam quam nulla porttitor massa. Nunc faucibus a pellentesque sit amet porttitor. Velit euismod in pellentesque massa. Commodo quis imperdiet massa tincidunt nunc pulvinar. Dui accumsan sit amet nulla
    facilisi morbi tempus. Eu volutpat odio facilisis mauris sit. At risus viverra adipiscing at in tellus integer. Pharetra sit amet aliquam id diam maecenas. Malesuada nunc vel risus commodo viverra maecenas accumsan lacus vel. Pharetra et ultrices
    neque ornare aenean euismod elementum nisi quis. Ut porttitor leo a diam sollicitudin. Est ultricies integer quis auctor. Natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient. Sapien nec sagittis aliquam malesuada bibendum arcu vitae elementum curabitur. Elit
    eget gravida cum sociis. Placerat duis ultricies lacus sed turpis tincidunt id. Sit amet mattis vulputate enim nulla. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Vulputate dignissim suspendisse in est. Est ultricies integer quis auctor elit sed vulputate mi
    sit. Ultricies tristique nulla aliquet enim tortor. Id neque aliquam vestibulum morbi blandit cursus. Volutpat blandit aliquam etiam erat. Erat pellentesque adipiscing commodo elit at imperdiet dui accumsan. Sed viverra tellus in hac habitasse. Elementum
    curabitur vitae nunc sed velit dignissim sodales. Eu turpis egestas pretium aenean pharetra magna. Arcu odio ut sem nulla pharetra diam sit amet. Aliquam sem et tortor consequat id porta nibh venenatis. Dictum non consectetur a erat nam at lectus
    urna duis. Tempus imperdiet nulla malesuada pellentesque elit eget gravida. Aliquet nec ullamcorper sit amet risus nullam eget felis. Posuere lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Vel elit scelerisque mauris pellentesque pulvinar pellentesque habitant morbi
    tristique. Mauris a diam maecenas sed enim.
  </p>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Scelerisque mauris pellentesque pulvinar pellentesque habitant morbi tristique. Odio ut enim blandit volutpat maecenas volutpat
    blandit aliquam. Id semper risus in hendrerit gravida rutrum. Nunc scelerisque viverra mauris in aliquam sem fringilla ut morbi. Vestibulum sed arcu non odio euismod lacinia at quis risus. Facilisis volutpat est velit egestas dui id ornare arcu odio.
    Dignissim suspendisse in est ante in nibh mauris cursus. Eget mi proin sed libero enim sed faucibus turpis. Risus nullam eget felis eget. Risus commodo viverra maecenas accumsan lacus. Faucibus nisl tincidunt eget nullam non nisi est. Eleifend mi
    in nulla posuere sollicitudin aliquam. Id consectetur purus ut faucibus pulvinar elementum integer enim. Et leo duis ut diam quam nulla porttitor massa. Cras semper auctor neque vitae. Magna sit amet purus gravida quis blandit turpis. Egestas diam
    in arcu cursus. Amet mattis vulputate enim nulla aliquet porttitor lacus luctus. Commodo viverra maecenas accumsan lacus vel facilisis volutpat est. Morbi tincidunt augue interdum velit euismod in pellentesque massa placerat. Sed arcu non odio euismod
    lacinia. Pellentesque pulvinar pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus. Mi bibendum neque egestas congue. Justo nec ultrices dui sapien eget mi proin sed libero. Senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Nisi scelerisque eu ultrices
    vitae auctor eu augue ut. Vitae et leo duis ut diam quam nulla porttitor massa. Nunc faucibus a pellentesque sit amet porttitor. Velit euismod in pellentesque massa. Commodo quis imperdiet massa tincidunt nunc pulvinar. Dui accumsan sit amet nulla
    facilisi morbi tempus. Eu volutpat odio facilisis mauris sit. At risus viverra adipiscing at in tellus integer. Pharetra sit amet aliquam id diam maecenas. Malesuada nunc vel risus commodo viverra maecenas accumsan lacus vel. Pharetra et ultrices
    neque ornare aenean euismod elementum nisi quis. Ut porttitor leo a diam sollicitudin. Est ultricies integer quis auctor. Natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient. Sapien nec sagittis aliquam malesuada bibendum arcu vitae elementum curabitur. Elit
    eget gravida cum sociis. Placerat duis ultricies lacus sed turpis tincidunt id. Sit amet mattis vulputate enim nulla. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Vulputate dignissim suspendisse in est. Est ultricies integer quis auctor elit sed vulputate mi
    sit. Ultricies tristique nulla aliquet enim tortor. Id neque aliquam vestibulum morbi blandit cursus. Volutpat blandit aliquam etiam erat. Erat pellentesque adipiscing commodo elit at imperdiet dui accumsan. Sed viverra tellus in hac habitasse. Elementum
    curabitur vitae nunc sed velit dignissim sodales. Eu turpis egestas pretium aenean pharetra magna. Arcu odio ut sem nulla pharetra diam sit amet. Aliquam sem et tortor consequat id porta nibh venenatis. Dictum non consectetur a erat nam at lectus
    urna duis. Tempus imperdiet nulla malesuada pellentesque elit eget gravida. Aliquet nec ullamcorper sit amet risus nullam eget felis. Posuere lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Vel elit scelerisque mauris pellentesque pulvinar pellentesque habitant morbi
    tristique. Mauris a diam maecenas sed enim.
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: This solution just squashes the content and mobile styles does not get applied since its still a desktop view.

Comment: @Karolis Maybe try changing the userAgent? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23248525/setting-a-custom-useragent-in-html-or-javascript

Answer (score -1):

I figured out I have to put my website in an iframe