# Set useragent in WKWebview

Tags: ios, user-agent, wkwebview

How do I set a custom useragent string in a WKWebView? I'm trying to embed the version of my app so that my server-side can see what features are available. I found the following method:

```
let userAgent = "MyApp/1.33.7"
request.setValue(userAgent, forHTTPHeaderField: "User-Agent")

NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()) {(response, data, error) in
    let content = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    self.web!.loadHTMLString(content!, baseURL: url)
}
self.web!.loadRequest(request);
```

But this means the useragent is only set for that single request. The first other request (e.g. a forward), will mean the useragent is reset to default again. How can I more permanently configure the wkwebview to use my custom useragent string?

Comment: Use the same method as for UIWebView described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/478387/change-user-agent-in-uiwebview-iphone-sdk

Comment: That does have a nice solution, using the defaults dictionary, which seems to be working :-) Only thing I'm not sure about is how to get the existing userAgent string from the WKWebView. Any ideas on this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [WKWebview set user agent OS X Yosemite](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26434269/wkwebview-set-user-agent-os-x-yosemite)

Answer (score 99, accepted):

You'll be happy to hear that `WKWebView` just gained a `customUserAgent` property in `iOS 9` and `OSX 10.11`

Example:

```
wkWebView.customUserAgent = "your agent"
```

Comment: @haykam yes wkWebView.customUserAgent = "your agent"

Comment: You can also append to it and not change the whole thing see [Marián Černý answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50910170/2870783)

Answer (score 36):

**Update:**

As of iOS 9.0 it is possible to set the user agent directly (as stated in other answers). But it is important to note that setting it will completely override the default user agent. If for some reason you need to just append a custom user agent use one of the following approaches.

```
webView.evaluateJavaScript("navigator.userAgent") { [weak webView] (result, error) in
    if let webView = webView, let userAgent = result as? String {
        webView.customUserAgent = userAgent + "/Custom Agent"
    }
}
```

or by using a sacrificial UIWebView

```
webView.customUserAgent = (UIWebView().stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: "navigator.userAgent") ?? "") + "/Custom agent"
```

---

**Old answer:**

As noted in my comment you can use the same approach as described here: [Change User Agent in UIWebView (iPhone SDK)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/478387/change-user-agent-in-uiwebview-iphone-sdk)

Now if you want to get the user agent you need to have an instance of a WKWebView and evaluate this javascript on it:

```
navigator.userAgent
```

The problem is that if you set a custom user agent after a WKWebView has been instantiated you will always get the same user agent. To solve this problem you have to reinstantiate the web view. Here is a sample how this might look:

```
self.wkWebView = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;

[self.wkWebView evaluateJavaScript:@"navigator.userAgent" completionHandler:^(id result, NSError *error) {
    __strong typeof(weakSelf) strongSelf = weakSelf;

    NSString *userAgent = result;
    NSString *newUserAgent = [userAgent stringByAppendingString:@" Appended Custom User Agent"];

    NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:newUserAgent, @"UserAgent", nil];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:dictionary];

    strongSelf.wkWebView = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:strongSelf.view.bounds];

    // After this point the web view will use a custom appended user agent
    [strongSelf.wkWebView evaluateJavaScript:@"navigator.userAgent" completionHandler:^(id result, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"%@", result);
    }];
}];
```

The code above will log:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 8_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/600.1.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/12B411 Appended Custom User Agent
```

#### Alternative

This could be made even simpler by using a "sacrificial" UIWebView since it evaluates javascript synchronously.

```
UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
NSString *userAgent = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"navigator.userAgent"];
NSString *newUserAgent = [userAgent stringByAppendingString:@" Appended Custom User Agent"];
NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:newUserAgent, @"UserAgent", nil];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:dictionary];

self.wkWebView = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
[self.wkWebView evaluateJavaScript:@"navigator.userAgent" completionHandler:^(id result, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"%@", result);
}];
```

Which logs the same thing:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 8_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/600.1.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/12B411 Appended Custom User Agent
```

Right now UIWebView and WKWebView use the same user agent but this approach might cause problems if that changes in the future.

Comment: the alternative way is more graceful

Comment: On iOS 10.3.3 I can change `customUserAgent` and it takes effect without needing to re-instantiate `WKWebView`.

Answer (score 26):

### Custom User Agent

To set a custom User Agent you can use `customUserAgent` property:

```
let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
let webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
webView.customUserAgent = "ExampleApp/1.0 (iPhone)"
```

Available: iOS 9+

### Append to the default User Agent

To append a custom string at the and of the default user agent you can use `applicationNameForUserAgent` property:

```
let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
webConfiguration.applicationNameForUserAgent = "ExampleApp/1.0 (iPhone)"
let webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
```

Then it will look for example like:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 11_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/604.4.7
(KHTML, like Gecko) ExampleApp/1.0 (iPhone)
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Available: iOS 9+

Comment: I looked at your solution and set the `webConfiguration.applicationNameForUserAgent` as described. But the just prints only `ExampleApp/1.0 (iPhone)` after setting it. And Not the entire string `Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 11_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/604.4.7
(KHTML, like Gecko) ExampleApp/1.0 (iPhone)`

Comment: If you want to programmatically construct your applicationNameForUser agent you can do     
    `NSDictionary *bundleInfo = [NSBundle mainBundle].infoDictionary; NSString *applicationName = bundleInfo[(NSString *)kCFBundleNameKey];  NSString *build = bundleInfo[(NSString *)kCFBundleVersionKey];  NSString *deviceModel = [[UIDevice currentDevice] model];  NSString *myApplicatiopnNameForUserAgent =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@ (%@)", applicationName, build, deviceModel];`. I think this would be nice if added to the answer if some one could translate it to swift. @Marián Černý

Answer (score 2):

`WKWebView` Swift 3 example:

```swift
let userAgentValue = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_5) AppleWebKit/603.2.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.1.1 Safari/603.2.4"
webView.customUserAgent = userAgentValue
```

---

Note to those who try to do this using Storyboard or Interface Builder: Unfortunately, Xcode doesn't currently support using `WKWebView` in Storyboards (Xcode version 8.3.2), so you have to add the web view manually in your code.

`UIWebView` Swift 3 example:

```swift
UserDefaults.standard.register(defaults: ["UserAgent": userAgentValue])
```

Answer (score 2):

**the default User-Agent in WKWebView is as**

```
Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 13_3 like Mac OS X)
```

You can customize the WKWebView User-Agent

```
webView.customUserAgent = "zgpeace User-Agent"
```

I write a demo for WKWebView:

```
func requestWebViewAgent() {
        print("requestWebViewAgent")

        let webView = WKWebView()
        webView.evaluateJavaScript("navigator.userAgent") { (userAgent, error) in
            if let ua = userAgent {
                print("default WebView User-Agent > \(ua)")
            }

            // customize User-Agent
            webView.customUserAgent = "zgpeace User-Agent"
        }
    }
```

**Warning: "User-Agent" is nil from webView, when webView is released. You can set webView object as property to keep the webView.**

**NSURLSession send User-Agent by default**. 
default User-Agent style like.

```
"User-Agent" = "UserAgentDemo/1 CFNetwork/1121.2.1 Darwin/19.2.0";
```

We can customize the User-Agent.

```
let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
config.httpAdditionalHeaders = ["User-Agent": "zgpeace User-Agent"]
```

I write a demo for URLSession in the below.

```
     func requestUrlSessionAgent() {
        print("requestUrlSessionAgent")

        let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        // default User-Agent: "User-Agent" = "UserAgentDemo/1 CFNetwork/1121.2.1 Darwin/19.2.0";
        // custom User-Agent
        config.httpAdditionalHeaders = ["User-Agent": "zgpeace User-Agent"]
        let session = URLSession(configuration: config)

        let url = URL(string: "https://httpbin.org/anything")!
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "GET"

        let task = session.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in

            // ensure there is no error for this HTTP response
            guard error == nil else {
                print ("error: \(error!)")
                return
            }

            // ensure there is data returned from this HTTP response
            guard let content = data else {
                print("No data")
                return
            }

            // serialise the data / NSData object into Dictionary [String : Any]
            guard let json = (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: content, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers)) as? [String: Any] else {
                print("Not containing JSON")
                return
            }

            print("gotten json response dictionary is \n \(json)")
            // update UI using the response here
        }

        // execute the HTTP request
        task.resume()

    }
```

**NSURLConnection send User-Agent by default**. 
default User-Agent style like.

```
"User-Agent" = "UserAgentDemo/1 CFNetwork/1121.2.1 Darwin/19.2.0";
```

We can customize the User-Agent.

```
urlRequest.setValue("URLConnection zgpeace User-Agent", forHTTPHeaderField: "User-Agent")
```

I write a demo for URLConnection in the below.

```
func requestUrlConnectionUserAgent() {
    print("requestUrlConnectionUserAgent")

    let url = URL(string: "https://httpbin.org/anything")!
    var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
    urlRequest.httpMethod = "GET"
    // default User-Agent: "User-Agent" = "UserAgentDemo/1 CFNetwork/1121.2.1 Darwin/19.2.0";
    urlRequest.setValue("URLConnection zgpeace User-Agent", forHTTPHeaderField: "User-Agent")

    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(urlRequest, queue: OperationQueue.main) { (response, data, error) in
        // ensure there is no error for this HTTP response
        guard error == nil else {
            print ("error: \(error!)")
            return
        }

        // ensure there is data returned from this HTTP response
        guard let content = data else {
            print("No data")
            return
        }

        // serialise the data / NSData object into Dictionary [String : Any]
        guard let json = (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: content, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers)) as? [String: Any] else {
            print("Not containing JSON")
            return
        }

        print("gotten json response dictionary is \n \(json)")
        // update UI using the response here
    }

  }
```

Demo in github: 
https://github.com/zgpeace/UserAgentDemo.git

Answer (score 0):

In my swift 3 case, I need entire app using a custom userAgent, here is my solution in AppDelegate. Here using UIWebview is because I don't need to set up the **WKWebViewConfiguration**, because I just only need the userAgent string

```
 fileprivate func setupGlobalWebviewUserAgent() {

    let webview = UIWebView()
    var newUserAgent = webview.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: "navigator.userAgent")
    newUserAgent = newUserAgent?.appending("custom user agent")
    let dictionary = Dictionary(dictionaryLiteral: ("UserAgent", newUserAgent))
    UserDefaults.standard.register(defaults: dictionary)
}
```

Comment: This is not related to wkWebView. :(

Comment: @KarthikKumar `UserDefaults.standard` is effective for `UIWebView` and `WKWebView`.