# IE 10,9,8: Can userAgent be changed through a javascript code?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9, internet-explorer-10, user-agent

I found the code to set the userAgent at runtime in my application,in IE11 Chrome and FF by **definegetter**. Same doesn't work in IE10,9,8. Is this even possible?
Referred [Mocking a useragent in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1307013/mocking-a-useragent-in-javascript)

**EDIT**

My *Tryout code* in IE 8 which didnt work.Error comes

***Object doesnt support this action*** 
Object.defineProperty as said by *TechLiam* works in FF, Chrome and IE9+

```
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf('MSIE 8.') != -1){
            try 
            { 
                delete navigator; 
            } 
            catch(e) 
            { 
                //window["navigator"] = undefined; 
                if(Object.defineProperty){
                    Object.defineProperty(navigator,'userAgent',{
                      get: function() { return bValue; },
                      set: function(newValue) { bValue = newValue; },

                      configurable: true
                    });
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think thia https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty#Internet_Explorer_8_specific_notes may help have a look at the Browser compatibility table and the Specifications table as they can tell you alot about what this is meant to do

Comment: #TechLiam I am not able to set navigator userAgent in IE8. Was able to do it through defineProperty in all other browsers. Read the link u had given above. I tried to modify existing property 'navigator' by first deleting it and creating a new one.See my edit for the tryout I made