# Testing navigator.browserLanguage or navigator.language with Sinon.js

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js, sinon, web-component-tester

How to use `sandbox.stub` of Testing framework [Sinon](http://sinonjs.org/) to overwrite e.g. `navigator.language` or `navigator.userAgent` for testing?

When I try to use the following:

```
suite('agent', function () {
  var sandbox;
  setup(function () {
    // create sandbox environment for mocking about
    sandbox = sinon.sandbox.create();
  });
  teardown(function () {
    // restore the environment as it was before
    sandbox.restore();
  });
  test('language', function () {
    assert.equal(au.env.agent.language, navigator.language);
    if (!navigator.language) assert.equal(au.env.agent.language, 'de');
    var lang = "test_URK";
    sandbox.stub(window.navigator, 'language', lang);
    assert.equal(au.env.agent.language, lang);
  });
});
```

then I'll get the following error: **Cannot stub non-existent own property language**:

Non of these stubs work as expected:

- sandbox.stub(window.navigator, 'language', lang);
- sandbox.stub(navigator, 'browserLanguage', lang);

are mocking the **navigator object**.

Any hints?

Answer (score 3):

As described in [Mocking a useragent in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1307013/mocking-a-useragent-in-javascript), you can:

```
  navigator.__defineGetter__('language', function(){
      return 'foo';
  });
```

<s>Or the more modern:</s>

```
  Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'language', {
      get: function() {return 'bar';}
  });
```

Comment: This does not work for me, getting `TypeError: Attempting to change access mechanism for an unconfigurable property.` using jasmine + karma.

Comment: my bad. In my sample code I had both, and the defineProperty worked after __defineGetter__, but when I commented out __defineGetter__, I got the same error as you.

Comment: `defineProperty` works when you use a property descriptor like so:             `Object.defineProperty(window.navigator, 'language', {value: 'en-US', configurable: true});`

Answer (score 1):

No need for Sinon here. The problem is, at least Chrome + Safari prevent changes to navigator.language (and others), as they are read-only. 
But you can just recreate the whole navigator object, as you anyway mocking it out.

```
navigator = {
    userLanguage: 'de',
    language: 'en'
};
```

In my tests, I would then just define the desired language before calling my functions.

```
// eg: following fn returns navigator.userLanguage || navigator.language;
navigator.userLanguage = undefined; // non IE
LanguageRedirection.getBrowserLanguage().then(function(lang){
   expect(res).toEqual('en');
});
```

Answer (score -2):

This worked for me:

```
sinon.stub(global, "navigator").returns({
  userAgent: "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.90 Safari/537.36"
});
```