# Mock navigator language in specific tests

Tags: javascript, jasmine, navigator

I am using Jasmine for testing JavaScript code and I was wondering if there is a way to set navigator language (or the browser language) for specific tests?

Answer (score 11):

As described in [Mocking a useragent in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1307013/mocking-a-useragent-in-javascript), you can:

```
  navigator.__defineGetter__('language', function(){
      return 'foo';
  });
```

Or, you can use the more modern:

```
  Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'language', {
      get: function() {return 'bar';}
  });
```

Comment: With the more modern, I got this issue: 

Attempting to change access mechanism for an unconfigurable property.
defineProperty@[native code]

Comment: Similar error here:     TypeError: Cannot redefine property: language
        at Function.defineProperty (<anonymous>)

Comment: Object.define will not work in this case because `navigator` read only and that property is non-configurable, ie it's `configurable` attribute is set to false.

Answer (score 4):

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38382371) from @abendigo works but it would indeed show 'Cannot redefine property' when you're trying to overrule the property twice.

In the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1307013/mocking-a-useragent-in-javascript) that he linked to they suggested to add `configurable: true`, so:

```
Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'language', {
  get: function() { return 'bar'; }, // Or just get: () => 'bar',
  configurable: true
});
```

Btw, a getter is not a must, you can also use a value notation:

```
Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'language', {
  value: 'bar',
  configurable: true
});
```